# Use of 'ArrayValued' in Matlab numerical integration

Tags: matlab, integral

Why when performing numerical integration in Matlab with `integral` does this case need `'ArrayValued'` to be set to `true`:

```
f = @(x) 5;
integral(f,0,2,'ArrayValued',true)
```

... while in this case the option isn't needed?:

```
f = @(x) x;
integral(f,0,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`integral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#btbbkta-1-fun) describing the integrand argument:

> For scalar-valued problems, the function `y = fun(x)` must accept a
> vector argument, `x`, and return a vector result, `y`. This generally
> means that `fun` must use array operators instead of matrix operators.
> For example, use `.*` (`times`) rather than `*` (`mtimes`). If you set the
> `'ArrayValued'` option to `true`, then fun must accept a scalar and return
> an array of fixed size.

So, a constant function like `f = @(x) 5` does not return a result the same size as `x` if `x` is a vector. The `integral` function requires this because under the hood it is vectorized for scalar functions for performance – it actually evaluates the integrand at multiple points simultaneously with a single function call.

You can make your constant function compliant and not require `'ArrayValued'` to be `true` with something like this:

```
f = @(x) 5+0*x;
integral(f,0,2)
```